# Adding "..ALL" to a dynamic parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to bring in all the values in a specific field to populate a parameter. I can do so, but I also want to add the word "..ALL" to the head of the list so the parameter essentially becomes optional.

When I choose a new data source, I don't seem to have the option of entering a SQL statement to pull the values, I can only choose a field to draw values from.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the `Add Command` option right under the datasource name in the database expert? This let's you enter the sql so you can union the hardcoded 'ALL' option.

Or, you could always use a view or stored procedure.

Comment: I created the report using the Add Command from the database expert. However, I am trying to create a dynamic parameter. When I choose Dynamic for List of Values and click on New data source, it doesn't seem to allow me to create another SQL statement to pull in the parameters, only select a field from the original statement. Therefore, I cannot add an "..ALL". 

Any ideas?

Comment: ahh I see. I always add the dynamic parameter datasource through the database expert, making sure not to link it to the main report's data. I never understood what that New DataSource Button is supposed to do.

Comment: Oh wait it's not a button. It's just misleading in that it calls it "New" when you are really selecting an existing datasource.

Comment: I have no idea what the Existing drop down is for...never used it.